# Rails - What is the maximum number of resque workers I can run in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, resque

Right now I'm running 3 resque workers to run the background jobs. My system has around *50K* users and there are many jobs pending in the Queue.

1. Can I increase the number of resque workers, but that should not affect the performance of the site.
2. What is the maximum number of resque workers I can run in production?

Comment: "that should not affect the performance of the site." Are you saying that the workers would be competing for resources with the rails site? (e.g. they're on the same machine?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale up the number of workers you run to as many as you would like as long as the computer you're running them on can handle the load. This number is going to vary from machine to machine and application to application; you'll have to do some testing to see what the limits are for your application and hardware (though in general, if your workers load your Rails app, memory tends to be the main constraint).

Keep in mind that the workers don't have to run on the same box that runs the Rails application. We are currently running 11 workers over about 9 queues (9 of the workers are dedicated to one or more specific queues, while 2 of them are wildcard workers) on a dedicated server, and we are considering upping our worker count by either getting a beefier EC2 instance or firing up a second instance to run additional workers on.